# Save array of drawable to file Android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-drawable

im trying to save an arraylist of drawable to a file.

Here is my class.

```
public class SeccionItem implements Serializable{
    String name;
    String text;
    ArrayList<Drawable> img;

    SeccionItem()
    {
        img = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    }
}
```

I have an arraylist of that class and i want to write it to a file using objectoutputstream, but i think that drawable cant be serialized, so can i use another type to store the images? like bitmap?. or is there any other way to store that arraylist? overwriting writeObject method?.

Im using this method to download the images

```
  public static Drawable getBitmap(String image_url) {
      try {
        URL url = new URL(image_url);
        InputStream is = (InputStream)url.getContent();
        Drawable b= Drawable.createFromStream(is, " ");
        if(b==null){
            Log.d("this","null");
        }
        return b;
      }catch(Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          return null;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

neither `Bitmap` or `Drawable` are `serializable`. You could serialize the information to rebuild your `Drawable`. For instance you could serialize an `ArrayList<Integer>` where the Intever is the Drawable's id.

> that drawables are downloaded from internet, i want to store it so
>   next time i dont have to download it again.

So you can store it on the sdcard, and nex time you can check if the file exists or not.

To write a file

```
public static void copy(InputStream is, File out) throws IOException {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LEN];
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);
                try {
                        int read = 0;
                        while ((read = is.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_LEN)) >= 0) {
                                fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        }
                        fos.flush();
                } finally {
                        close(fos);
                }

                fos = null;
                buffer = null;
}
```

Comment: that drawables are downloaded from internet, i want to store it so next time i dont have to download it again.

Comment: sure, thats what im trying to do, but how can i store that arraylist if its not serializable?

Comment: Could you show me the part where you downlad the files from internet??

Comment: instead of createFromStream, write the drawable inside the sdcard

Comment: u mean storing the inputStream instead of converting to drawable? can i store an array of inputStream?